# SQLite Trigger to SQL Server Express 2008

Tags: sqlite, triggers, sql-server-2008-express

I need help on SQL Server syntax to create some triggres that I´ve used with success on SQLite, but I'm having trouble with **NEW.Table** once it´s not part of SQL Server.

That´s my SQLite trigger code:

```
UPDATE EngineeringItems set ElevacaoFIT = CAST(round((select "Position Z" - MatchingPipeOD / 2 from EngineeringItems where PnPId = new.PNPID), 0) as INT) where PNPID = new.PNPID;
```

**PNPID** is the table pk!

***EDIT 2:***

Thanks again buddy!
I´ve tried your new code with a little modifications and SQL Server accepted it and trigger was created successfully. So the code is:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [ElevacaoFIT_Insert]
   ON  [dbo].[EngineeringItems]
   AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE EngineeringItems
SET
    ElevacaoFIT = CAST(ROUND((select EngineeringItems."Position Z" - (EngineeringItems.MatchingPipeOD / 2)
FROM
    EngineeringItems INNER JOIN inserted ON EngineeringItems.PnPId = inserted.PnPId), 0) AS INT);
END
```

But now I get this message: **Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.**!  Any idea?

Sorry for bother you... Thanks again!!

Answer (score 1):

Can you post what you have tried on SQL Server?

Something like the following may do it:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[EngineeringItems_Trigger] 
   ON  [dbo].[EngineeringItems]
   AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

   UPDATE EngineeringItems
   SET
     ElevacaoFIT = CAST(round(("Position Z" - MatchingPipeOD / 2), 0) as INT)
   FROM
     EngineeringItems INNER JOIN inserted ON EngineeringItems.PnPId = inserted.PNPID;
END
```

Comment: Please check the modification to my answer. I believe this should work.

Comment: Bro... please take a look at Edit 2. Thanks!!